# Button to instanciate ViewController is not working after hiding it

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have this very weird problem that I just found out...

I have this `button` which is triggering this `function`:

```
@objc func vergessenTapped() {
    let forgotPasswordVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ForgotPasswordVC") as! ForgotPasswordVC
    forgotPasswordVC.email = self.emailTextField.text!
    self.present(forgotPasswordVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I also have these function which `hide`/`show` the `button` above:

```
    // delegate Methode für eye-Button
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    switch textField {
    case passwordTextField:
        if passwordTextField.text != "" {
            eyeButton.isHidden = false
            vergessenButton.isHidden = true
        } else {
            eyeButton.isHidden = true
        }

        break
    default:
        break
    }
    return true
}
// delegate Methode für eye-Button
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    
    if textField == passwordTextField {
        self.eyeButton.isHidden = true
        self.vergessenButton.isHidden = false
    }
    return true
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text == "" {
        self.eyeButton.isHidden = true
        self.vergessenButton.isHidden = false
    }else {
        self.vergessenButton.isHidden = true
        self.eyeButton.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Now the **Problem:**

When I press the `button` the first time before any of the `delegate-function` above are hiding it, the `ViewController` it `presents` works just fine.

However: As soon as the button is hidden for the first time, and the user clicks it after it is visible again the `forgotpasswordViewController` behaves really really weird, e.g:

**1.** when calling `self.dismiss` , the `ViewController is actually not dismissed, but is popping the one *below*  it.

```
@objc func backButtonTapped(){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**2.** The `button` in the `forgotpasswordViewController`  (only one button there)  is not doing anything.

Here is a [Screenvideo](https://gofile.io/d/s3h2CK) for a better understanding. 22 seconds into the video I start typing (somehow not visible on the screenvideo but you can see that the "vergessen" but disappears and appears again. After appearing again I click it and as you can see, neither the `backButton` nor the `confirmButton` work like they did before...

Is this some kind of bug??? I can't explain it .. so if anyone helps me out here I would really appreciated!

***Demo-Project:***

[Demo-Project](https://gofile.io/d/NsuFNw)

Comment: "when calling self.dismiss" Show that code please.

Comment: @matt  sure, updated the question

Comment: So what does "popping the one below it" mean? Is there a view controller you didn't tell us about? I feel this might have nothing to do with showing and hiding a button, but rather it is about your view controller hierarchy. Could we get a sense of that?

Comment: @matt first viewcontrollers pushes to this one, with all the functions above. And this Is then presentint the one where the strange things are Happening after the button is hidden and unhidden again

Comment: OK I'm not getting a clear picture. Can you reproduce the problem in a simple project consisting of just these three view controllers (and the navigation controller) and post it?

Comment: @matt I tried but I cant... will update the question tomorrow with a Screenvideo and some other stuff that might help, but have to sleep now :D

Comment: @matt hey matt, I added a Screenvideo

Comment: That's very good. Now create a mock-up project with those three view controllers and make it downloadable. I feel sure the problem lies elsewhere and has nothing to do with the showing/hiding of the button, but you are not telling us anything about the "elsewhere" code. So the only way is to see it.

Comment: @matt updated the question again, demo project as you wished. Maybe that helps

Comment: Perfect, very simplified and I can reproduce the problem. Thank you, let me look at it and get back to you.

Comment: @matt youre welcome, appreciate your help!

Comment: I've solved it, hang on a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with showing and hiding the Vergessen button. The problem is this sort of thing in your ForgotPassword view controller (and your other view controller too, actually):

```
let backButton: UIButton = {
    let v = UIButton()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.setImage(UIImage(named:"down"), for: .normal)
    v.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return v
}()
```

There is something very wrong with that. Do you see what it is? Of course not, because this is one of the nastiest little traps in all of iOS programming. You cannot say `v.addTarget(self...` in the initializer of an instance property. Why? Because the instance `self` (here, the view controller) is what we are in the middle of initializing. So `self` has no meaning here. Well, sometimes it has a meaning and sometimes it doesn't; the real trap for you is that the code *ever* worked. That really misled you. (Also you were misled by the fact that the code compiled. In my opinion, it should not. I have a [filed a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4865), if it's any comfort.)

Okay, so I can think of a lot of solutions, but traditionally what we do here is replace `let` with `lazy var`. I think I see six places in your code where you need to do that.

```
lazy var backButton: UIButton = { // ... and so on
```

And when you do, everything will start working just fine.

The reason this fixes the problem is that `lazy` postpones the running of that code until *after* the view controller itself has been initialized. So then `self` means what it is supposed to mean.

(I'm sorry there is no `lazy let`, but there's nothing I can do about that. You just have to say `lazy var` and let it go at that.)

I should also add that, new in iOS 14, you can (if you wish) stop calling `addTarget(_:action:for:)`, and that way you won't fall into this trap ever again. But the fix, which is to add a UIAction to the button, is only on iOS 14 and later.

Comment: matt, what can I say.. really appreciate your help man ! Like you said yourself, I never wouldve found this by myself. I do have one question though, why does it work if I don't type anything in the text field and click on the button immediately ???

Comment: I knew you'd ask me that, and I have prepared an answer: "Don't know. Mongo only pawn in game of life!" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfdvSD6yRck

Comment:  youre the man .. I just fixed and everything works perfectly fine again thanks to you. Really appreciated!

Comment: I did some more experimentation. The bug is elicited because in your `vergessenTapped` you forgot to call `endEditing`. If you do that first, before creating and presenting the password VC, the problem goes away.

Comment: However, what I said about changing `let` to `lazy var` still applies. That keeps us from falling into this situation in the first place.